# ¿Tiene sentido editar una publicación marcando `palabras` como código?

Tags: discusión, ediciones, ediciones-sugeridas

Cada vez me encuentro más sugerencias de edición ([como esta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/188204)) en la que se pasa de un texto del tipo:

> Tenemos dos ramas principales: máster y develop. Cuando hemos necesitado hemos necesitado hacer cambios creabamos desde develop features para ir avanzando en nuestro desarrollo. Una vez que en el feature creado veíamos que estaba todo ok lo subíamos a develop.
>
> (...) ¿Qué pasa? Pues que cuando intento hacer un release no me deja debido a esos cambios hechos desde el server.

A algo del tipo:

> Tenemos dos ramas principales: `máster` y `develop`. Cuando hemos necesitado hacer cambios creábamos desde `develop` `features` para ir avanzando en nuestro desarrollo. Una vez que en el `feature` creado veíamos que estaba todo ok lo subíamos a `develop`.
>
> (...) ¿Qué pasa? Pues que cuando intento hacer un release no me deja debido a esos cambios hechos desde el `server`.

Es decir, se utiliza el código para resaltar palabras clave, variables o nombres programáticos (en este caso, nombres de ramas de Git).

¿Son buenas estas ediciones? ¿Debo aceptarlas?

A mí personalmente me tienta más usar cursivas para las palabras clave (o negrita, con moderación) y solamente usar código para las cosas estrictamente de código.

Comment: Si mi opinión vale de algo, creo que es perfectamente razonable lo que dices: yo también evitaría el uso de la etiqueta code en todo aquello que no fuese estrictamente código; por otro lado, al menos en los ejemplos que propones, las palabras resaltadas tienen una equivalente apropiada en castellano. No comparto la moda de no traducirlas, tenemos un idioma tremendamente rico.

Comment: Tu opinión siempre sirve, GuardabosqueS

Comment: Un placer, @fedorqui

Comment: Me parece que aquí lo central es que se dando formato a ciertas palabras que forman parte de enunciados de lenguaje natural, no de código. Si las ediciones hacen *más claro* los enunciados deberían aceptarse, si no lo hacen más claro deberían rechazarse. Ahora bien sobre la forma específica de dar formato a ciertas palabras, me parece que sería una discusión interesante pero "principalmente basada en opiniones", de hecho creo que ya se ha discutido. En el caso específico aquí mostrado, asumiendo que no hay ningún otro cambio que resulte relevante **sugiero rechazar** la sugerencia de edición.

Comment: en mi caso, cuando tenia poca reputación para editar, con solo colocar una linea de codigo no es suficiente, por ello empezaba a adornar mas la pregunta obvio lo hacia para cumplir la edición  y poder ganarme los dos puntos, ahora lo hago por deber y editando estrictamente lo necesario; ahora, ¿si es valido?, en algunos casos todos pasamos por esa vía para buscar unos puntillos

Comment: y [dejo una pregunta parecida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/188211) que se debe hacer

Comment: En las preguntas/respuestas yo uso `codigo` para todo aquello que tenga que ver con el código, por ejemplo, si hablo de una `funcionCualquieraDelLenguaje()` lo pongo así, y pongo el enlace a esa función. Siempre lo he hecho así y no pienso cambiar. Hay algo de lo que quizá haya estado abusando últimamente y es de usarlo en los comentarios a preguntas para referir mensajes de error ([ejemplo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/315938/error-de-consulta-problemas-de-concatenación/315984#comment573237_315938)). Y eso lo reproduzco en la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/315984/29967).

Comment: @A.Cedano lo que yo comento no es sobre código, sino sobre palabras genéricas como la que enlacé en la pregunta (y [otras similares](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/188218)) que se siguen haciendo y aceptando). El uso que comentas a mí me parece aceptable, más que nada porque la cursiva en comentarios no resalta demasiado.

Comment: @fedorqui es precisamente por eso por lo que lo uso también en los comentarios, poniéndolo muchas veces también en cursiva. Lo que no me queda claro es si eso es reconocido como código por los bots y demás.

Comment: Es interesante lo que comentan, obviamente todos tenemos una cierta perspectiva acerca de como una pregunta o respuesta se ve más comprensible, en lo personal indicar el nombre de una clase o una variable me parecía que estaba correcto mostrarla como parte de código, aunque ahora que se menciona estos puntos si, me parece correcto el resaltar con cursiva o negrilla (según la importancia que tiene el texto) y que tanto tenga que ver con el código que normalmente se adjunta para mostrar el problema o respuesta y solo usar un indicador de código cuando verdaderamente es código.

Answer (score 10):

En este caso particular tiene sentido la parte en que master y develop son nombres de variables o identificadores que podríamos meter en un comando de github, ahora poner *server* o *feature* como si fuera posible usarlo en un comando git con todo lo demás no está bien, lo correcto es rechazar su edición ya que la mayoría de las cosas marcadas semánticamente como código no son código, y eso nos afecta a los lectores y afecta a los bots.

Comment: Ajá, interesante. Exacto, hay partes que sí son útiles pero otras que no. El resultado final es algo probablemente demasiado lleno de recursos visuales que hacen que la publicación sea poco leíble. Para este caso concreto, he dejado [un comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/313070/no-se-pudo-conectar-a-bd-sql-server#comment572142_313070) al usuario en otra de sus ediciones. Para el caso general: ¿qué debería hacerse si parte de la edición es buena y parte es mala?

Answer (score 1):

En mi opinión depende un poco del contexto de la pregunta y del idioma.

Aquí uno de los "problemas" es que escribimos en español/castellano. En una publicación en Inglés no tendría mucho sentido aplicar formato a palabras como *server*.

Sí que creo que sería correcto/aceptable resaltarla de algún modo (probablemente cursiva) en una publicación en español; aunque sería algo opcional, ya que entiendo que cualquier persona que use stackoverflow no tendrá problema en leer esa palabra en inglés dentro del contexto de una pregunta formulada en español... Otra opción es haberla escrito directamente en español.

Respecto al resto de etiquetas (master, develop, feature), y puesto que la pregunta del ejemplo es una pregunta sobre *Git*, no veo mal que se marquen como código, ya que o bien son nombres de ramas, o de términos usados en *gitflow*. Aunque por no mezclar ramas con términos probablemente sería mejor dejar *feature* como cursiva.

Sería un caso distinto si la pregunta fuese sobre alguna duda con un lenguaje de programación y se hiciera referencia a *Git* de refilón. Por poner un ejeplo tonto:

Ayer hice `push` de este código que no me funciona `const a = a + 1` a la rama `master`

Aquí en este caso el marcado de *push* y *master* no aportan nada y se *mezclan* con lo importante, que es el código.

En definitiva, en la pregunta original creo que no se debería haber aprobado (pero tampoco rechazado, ya que algunas cosas eran correctas), se podría haber hecho una nueva edición para mejorarla. Al final será dificil tener una norma general y se tendrá que mirar un poco el contexto.

Comment: Tu ejemplo es muy bueno. Un `push` no queda mal, pero si se junta en una frase con otros elementos de código, crea un exceso de elementos visuales que (para mí) dificultan la lectura.